# Navigation Bar Wrapper HTML

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to create a website with a navigation bar that stays the same way through resizing a web browser. So that it will stay (eg. 10px) the sides. I remember using a

```
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
}
.nav {
    flex:(I forget)
}
```

and it would do what I wanted.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: And it will be good if you can share your full code here at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like that..

```
.nav {
    -webkit-flex: 1; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helped me!

Comment: #nathansinger glad to help :)